# React Native - How can I change the TextInput cursor position

Tags: android, react-native

How can I set the cursor position in a TextInput field with a button and still be able to change the position normally by pressing on a certain point on the text?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62488034/14223224

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of your selection manually (done through `selection` and `onSelectionChange` properties):

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("test")
  const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState({start:0, end: 0})

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <TextInput 
        style={{borderWidth: 1}} 
        value={text}
        onChangeText={newText => setText(newText)}
        selection={selection}
        onSelectionChange={({ nativeEvent: { selection, text } }) => setSelection(selection)}
        />
      <Button
       title="Press me"
       onPress={() => {
          setSelection({start: 2, end: 2})
       }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but sometimes when I select a word it jumps to the end of the word, or if the selected point that it needs to move to when pressing the button is in the middle of the word it jumps to the end. Do you by any chance know a fix for that because I can't seem to find an answer?